# How do you store a text file into an array with different string formats?

Tags: c#, arrays, file

Using C#. I am creating a program that stores movies in a text file such as:

38#Finding Nemo#Family#2001#yes

36#Wonder Woman#Action#2017#yes

35#Solo#Action#2018#yes

I am trying to process a batch transaction into my movie inventory file. This text file holds an action code after the first delimiter('#') whether to add, change, or delete a movie in the movie inventory file. The problem that I am having is that each line has a different format while I am trying to store it into an array. What is a way to read the header line differently and ignore empty values between delimiters?

An example batch file is:

H#Movie Inventory Updates#10/31/2019

D#C#5#Family Movie 1###no

D#A#21#Sci-Fi Movie 1#sci-fi#2005#yes

D#A#22#Other Movie 1#other#2001#yes

D#C#1###2002#

D#D#4####

```
    public static Batch[] ReadBatchFile()
    {
        Batch[] bTransactions = new Batch[100];

        if (File.Exists("batch_transaction.txt"))
        {
            StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader("batch_transaction.txt");
            //string path = "batch_transaction.txt";
            string line = inFile.ReadLine();
            while (line != null) //read all transaction records, ignoring header and footer
            {
                string[] tempArray = line.Split('#');
                bTransactions[Batch.GetCount()] = new Batch(tempArray[0], tempArray[1], int.Parse(tempArray[2]), tempArray[3], tempArray[4], double.Parse(tempArray[5]), tempArray[6]);
                Batch.SetCount(Batch.GetCount() + 1);
                line = inFile.ReadLine();
            }

            inFile.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File not found.");
        }
        return bTransactions;
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm currently trying to read in the the other lines:

```
    public Batch(string recordType, string actionCode, int movieId, string movieTitle, string movieGenre, double releaseYear, string inStock)
    {
        this.recordType = recordType;
        this.actionCode = actionCode;
        this.movieId = movieId;
        this.movieTitle = movieTitle;
        this.movieGenre = movieGenre;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;

    }
```

Comment: "Fix your source data," is so often a better solution than to try to parse poorly planned or inconsistent data output.

Comment: Wouldn't an object be easier?

Comment: Why not just process the first line before you enter the while loop?

Comment: It's a programming assignment where the batch file has to be formatted this way unfortunately.

Comment: The data is perfect and does not need replacement.  Anybody who thinks the input data is wrong should not be answering the question.  The line starting with #H# is a header line with a Date.  the line starting with D#C looks like a category (or maybe change) line telling type of movie.  the lines starting with D#A looks like add lines.  So the type of line (which may have different number of inputs) must be processed one at a time.